# error: package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

i trying to get display dimensions with using `LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode();` method. I can use it from DesktopLauncher, but i need use in a class named MainMenuScreen, which extends ApplicationAdapter. I imported `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;`, but i still get same error.

I put project structure from here, if it helps.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but `LwjglApplicationConfiguration` could be only available to desktop module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no way to import LwjglApplicationConfiguration package to MainMenuScreen, but i solved the why i need LwjglApplcationConfiguration package, i need it for scale textures by screen width and height in MainMenuScreen i can only get these informations from LwjglApplcationConfiguration package.
In the DesktopLauncher, we have this code for show MainMenuScreen.

```
new LwjglApplication(new MainMenuScreen(), config);
```

Then i wrote a simple constructor to MainMenuScreen as:

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends ApplicationAdapter
{
  //some methods and attributes in here.
  private float ScreenHeight;
  private float ScreenWidth;

 public MainMenuScreen(float height, float width)
 {
    ScreenHeight = height;
    ScreenWidth = width;
    System.out.println("I got the datas! Height:" + ScreenHeight + ", width: " + ScreenWidth);
 }
}
```

Of course, i should have change the MainMenuScreen() calling in LwjglApplication() at the begining as:

```
new LwjglApplication(new MainMenuScreen(config.height, config.width), config);
```